# Sharing modules and/or files on Windows 7

Tags: python

I have the following structure:

```
projectname/
  somefolder/
    somecode.py
    shared.py
  somefolder2/
    somecode2.py
    shared.py
```

There is a `__init__.py` file in each folder.

Here "shared.py" is exactly the same so I have to copy and paste it between somefolder and somefolder2.

I want to do the following:

1) Add a shared folder and put the shared.py in it:

```
shared/
    shared.py
```

2) Reference this in somecode.py and somecode2.py. I have tried:

```
from projectname.shared.shared import *
from ..shared.shared import *
```

I see for instance that boto (https://github.com/boto/boto/tree/develop/boto) nicely reference any path from anywhere in the project simply using paths like "boto.etc" so it must be possible.

EDIT: Changed title to include "Windows 7" and also note that I have read all the other explanations but they either suggest some hack in code or generally suggest *many* ways to do this in path, pythonpath and so on. I want one single solution for Python 2.7 on Windows 7 that simply works.

Update: Got a bit further by:
1. Adding python path as suggested in the approved answer here:
[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)
2. Ensuring `__init__.py` is properly set.
Status now is that I can reference the project and it's folders but not the code file in the folder. So:

```
from projectname.shared.shared import *
```

Here projectname.shared is found but not the last part which is the code-file.

Thanks,
Marius

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure projectname is in your sys.path, either by modifying the list, creating a .pth file somewhere in your sys.path locations, or setting your working directory to projectname. There may be other ways but those are the easiest ones.

Comment: I have added the working folder of the project to sys.path: http://screencast.com/t/uvqap3dDwWw